# How to exclude a specific package from the library jar in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, quickblox, smack

I am facing an error of duplicate entry between smack and quickblox libraries. After excluding some groups and modules, I can add two libraries, but I failed to add a third one because of this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/jivesoftware/smack/android/AndroidSmackInitializer.class

I have tried a lot of ways to fix this by packaging options and others but none of them didn't helped please help me to try to fix this.

My build.gradle file:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.messenger.Bolo"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
    
        }
        sourceSets {
            main {
                java {
                    exclude 'org/jivesoftware/smack/android/AndroidSmackInitializer.class'
                    exclude '**/AndroidSmackInitializer.class'
                }
            }
            androidTest {
                java {
                    exclude '**/AndroidSmackInitializer.class'
                    exclude 'org/jivesoftware/smack/android/AndroidSmackInitializer.class'
    
                }
            }
        }
    
        packagingOptions
                {
                    exclude 'BuildConfig.class'
                    exclude 'ExtensionsInitializer.class'
                    exclude 'AbstractXMPPConnection$8.class'
                    exclude 'MiniDnsResolver.class'
                    exclude 'XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.class'
                    exclude 'ExtensionsInitializer.class'
                    exclude 'AndroidSmackInitializer.class'
                    exclude 'XmppStringPrepUtil.class'
                    exclude 'org.jivesoftware.smack.android.AndroidSmackInitializer.class'
                    exclude 'org/jivesoftware/smack/android/AndroidSmackInitializer.class'
                    exclude '**/AndroidSmackInitializer.class'
                }
        configurations {
            all*.exclude group: 'org.jivesoftware.smack.android.AndroidSmackInitializer.class'
        }
    
        //useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
    
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
        compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.5'
        compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.5'
        compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.5'
        compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.5'
        compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-core:4.1.5'
        compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-resolver-dnsjava:4.1.5'
        compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:$rootProject.qbSdkVersion@aar") {
    
            exclude module: 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-resolver-dnsjava:4.1.6'
            exclude module: 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.6'
            exclude module: 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.6'
            exclude module: 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.6'
            exclude module: 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.6'
            exclude module: 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-core:4.1.6'
            exclude group: "org/jivesoftware/smack/android/**"
            exclude group: "org/jivesoftware/smack/android/AndroidSmackInitializer.class"
            exclude group: "org/jivesoftware/smack/android/**"
            exclude group: '**/AndroidSmackInitializer.class'
        }
        compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:$rootProject.qbSdkVersion@aar") {
    
            transitive = true
    
            exclude module: 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-resolver-dnsjava:4.1.5'
    
            exclude module: 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.5'
    
            exclude module: 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.5'
    
            exclude module: 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.5'
    
            exclude module: 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.5'
    
            exclude module: 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-core:4.1.5'
    
            exclude group: '**/AndroidSmackInitializer.class'
            //exclude module: 'org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.class'
    
           
    
           
       

 exclude group: "org/jivesoftware/smack/android/AndroidSmackInitializer.class"
        exclude group: "org/jivesoftware/smack/android/**"

    
        }
        compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:$rootProject.qbSdkVersion@aar") {
            //exclude module: 'support-v4'
            exclude module: 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-resolver-dnsjava:4.1.5'
            exclude module: 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.5'
            exclude module: 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.5'
            exclude module: 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.5'
            exclude module: 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.5'
            exclude module: 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-core:4.1.5'
            exclude group: "org/jivesoftware/smack/android/**"
            exclude group: "org/jivesoftware/smack/android/AndroidSmackInitializer.class"
            exclude group: "org/jivesoftware/smack/android/**"
            exclude group: '**/AndroidSmackInitializer.class'
    
    
        }
       
       
        compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')

    }
    task androidReleaseJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: assembleRelease) {
        from "$buildDir/intermediates/classes/release/"
        exclude 'org/jivesoftware/smack/android/AndroidSmackInitializer.class'
    
    }
```

Comment: Any update on this? androidTest -> java -> exclude is not working after updating from gradle 2.8. to 2.12